# Why do I get a None when trying to use a class function as element of a dict?

Tags: python, list, function, class, dictionary

I'm a python noob and I'm having trouble understanding why I keep getting a a printed None when I call on welcome_text() function.  Here is the full code:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, name, status):
        self.name = name
        self.status = 0

    def welcome_text(self):
        print "Welcome to the %s" % self.name   

class Catacombs(Room):
    pass

class Dungeon(Room):
    pass

my_dict = {0:['catacombs', Catacombs("Catacombs", 0), 'troll', 10],
           1:['dungeon', Dungeon("Dungeon", 0), 'demon', 20]
          }

print my_dict[0][1].welcome_text()
```

The above prints:

```
Welcome to the Catacombs
None
```

I'm interested in seeing if I can use a class function from list within a dict but I'm unsure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Because you are printing the return value of the `Room.welcome_text()` method. That method doesn't return *anything*, so the default `None` is returned instead. See the duplicate on how to fix this.

Comment: Other than that, you are doing fine; storing instances in a dict like this is a great approach.

Comment: Hi Martijn, I appreciate your response.  I'm new to SO and python so my search terms may not have been on point when I searched initially.  Apologies for any duplication.

Comment: That's fine; the duplicates are not always easy to find when you don't know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function welcome_text doesn't `return` a value, it just prints it. Change the `print` to `return`.

Comment: Oh, I see - that makes sense and it worked! Thank you for your time and assistance.